# Adding file uploads to a Sinatra tutorial

Tags: sinatra, carrierwave

EDIT - 'carrierwave' doesn't work with Sinatra 1.3.
Sinatra 1.2.7 rocks this code!

---

I'm learning Ruby, and just finished this awesome Sinatra tutorial:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/singing-with-sinatra-the-encore/

The complete, working code is here (no Bundler, so requires a couple gems to be installed)
http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/953_sinatra3/Source.zip

I feel good, I want to learn more! The next challenge I've set for myself is to add file uploading capability to that tutorial, and I'm stumped. I want to use Carrierwave, and am attempting to integrate it into the completed tutorial.

First, I'm requiring 'carrierwave' and 'carrierwave-datamapper':

```
require 'carrierwave'
require 'carrierwave/datamapper'
```

Then I'm creating a new class:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base    #via a Carrierwave tutorial
  storage :file
end
```

Adding to the Notes class:

```
class Note
include DataMapper::Resource
property :id, Serial
property :content, Text, :required => true
property :complete, Boolean, :required => true, :default => 0
property :created_at, DateTime
property :updated_at, DateTime
property :image, String, :auto_validation => false  # trying to add image uploading
mount_uploader :image, MyUploader                   # trying to add image uploading
end
```

Adding to post:

```
post '/' do
  n = Note.new
  n.content = params[:content]
  n.image = params[:image]      # trying to add image uploading
  n.created_at = Time.now
  n.updated_at = Time.now
  n.upload = 
  if n.save 
    redirect '/', :notice => 'Note created successfully.'
  else
    redirect '/', :error => 'Failed to save note.'
  end
end
```

Lastly, I'm adding uploading to the form:

```
<section id="add">
<form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea name="content" placeholder="Your note&hellip;"></textarea>
    <p><input type="file" name="image" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Take Note!">
</form>
</section>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave.rb:107:in `<top (required)>': private method `public' called for Sinatra::Application:Class (NoMethodError)
```

But of course if I don't require 'carrierwave', I get an error when MyUploader tries to inherit from it...

Thanks in advance for any tips. I feel so close here, and yet so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error looks like it's caused by a recent change to sinatra. This is in the [changelog for version 1.3](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/1.3.0/CHANGES#L48):

> Renamed `:public` to `:public_folder` to avoid overriding Ruby's built-in `public` method/keyword. `set(:public, ...)` is still possible but shows a warning. (Konstantin Haase)

Either check if there's a more recent version of carrierwave or use a previous version of sinatra.